# Can you use Output Feedback Mode (OFB) to construct a Message Authentication Code (MAC)

Tags: mac, ofb

Suppose $f_k$ is an arbitrary block cipher. Can OFB via $f_k$ be used to make a MAC. I argue that you can't even with fixed l, $m = l \times k$ because in OFB, $\mu = f_k(f_k(...((IV))) \oplus m$, and with an oracle, you would be able to get $\mu$ for a given message and find $f_k(f_k(...(IV)))$ and so can find $\mu$ for any message. However, I'm not sure I've used the oracle correctly, that is I'm not sure I can use the MAC provided by the oracle in such a way. Any help would be appreciated.